# Lie derivative of a vector field in coordinates

Tags: smooth-manifolds, lie-derivative, pushforward

I'm reading the proof that $L_XY=[X, Y]$ on page 225 [in this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=xQsTJJGsgs4C&q=225#v=snippet&q=225&f=false) and I believe it is not quite correct to due an error in equation 20.6. The author writes 
if $Y=\sum b^j \partial/\partial^j$, then 
$$\phi_{-t, *}(Y_{\phi_t(p)})=\sum_j b^j(\phi_t(p)) \phi_{-t, *}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}|_{\phi_t(p)}\right)=
\sum_{i,j} b^j(\phi_t(p)) \frac{\partial\phi^i}{\partial x^j}(-t, p)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}|_p$$
It seems to me that the RHS should be $\sum_{i,j} b^j(\phi_t(p)) \frac{\partial\phi^i}{\partial x^j}(-t, \phi_t(p))\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}|_p$ and that this error carries over to (20.7) as well as (20.8). However, since the final result of the author's calculation turns out to be $[X, Y]$ as expected, the error should have somehow disappeared. Any thoughts on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are correct: $\phi_{-t *}:T_{\phi_t(p)}M \to T_pM$ should satisfy $$ \phi_{-t *} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\rvert_{\phi_t(p)} \right) = \frac{\partial\phi^i_{-t}}{\partial x^j}(\phi_t(p)) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\rvert_p.$$

The author does rewrite this a couple of times, but in the end it does not really matter because we are eventually setting $t = 0$, and $\phi_0(p) = p$.

Comment: Hm, after reflection I agree that something fishy is going on here. At the very least, the $\phi_t(p)$ should make the chain rule more tricky to apply than how it is presented, for flows whose behavior is not uniform. In the special case you are considering, $\phi(t)(p) = (p^1+t,p^2,\ldots,p^n)$, there is no problem, since for any fixed $t$ the Jacobian of $\phi(t,p)$ with respect to $p^1,\ldots,p^n$ is the identity. Hence the problematic term vanishes from the computation.

Comment: Actually, this is how Lee proves this proposition in Introduction to Smooth Manifolds (Thm 18.2): choose rectifying coordinates where the field is $\dfrac{∂}{∂x^1}$, so that the flow is the one you have given. Since this flow is uniform, the time-derivative looks the same everywhere, so the kind of argument given in Tu's book applies without complications.

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't look trivial to me that since we are setting t=0, nothing should go wrong. In fact, with the correction above, the calculations in equation 20.8 are affected, because an additional application of chain rule is required which makes things somewhat messy. And yes, eventually the additional terms vanish. Maybe I've over complicated the calculations (in which case I would appreciate if you could let me know), but again it doesn't look like an obvious fix to me.

Answer (score 0):

I also stumbled across this error, and worked out the right derivative. I'll share the details of the computation, they might save someone some time.

We want to know the value of $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|_{t=0} \left[ \frac{\partial{\phi_i}}{\partial x^j}(-t, \phi_t(p))\right]$. The function we are computing the derivative of is the composition of
$$
f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{n+1},\ t \mapsto (-t, \phi_t(p)) 
$$
and $\frac{\partial\phi_i}{\partial x^j} : \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \to \mathbb{R}$.
We have that 
$$
df = \left(-1, \frac{\partial \phi^1}{\partial t}, \ldots, \frac{\partial \phi^n}
{\partial t} \right)^T
$$ 
and
$$
d\frac{\partial\phi_i}{\partial x^j} = \left ( \frac{\partial\phi_i}{\partial t \partial x^j}, \frac{\partial\phi_i}{\partial x^1 \partial x^j}, \ldots, \frac{\partial\phi_i}{\partial x^n \partial x^j} \right ).
$$
It follows from the chain rule that
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|_{t=0} \left[ \frac{\partial{\phi_i}}{\partial x^j}(-t, \phi_t(p))\right] = \left(d\frac{\partial\phi_i}{\partial x^j}\right)_{f(0)} (df)_0 = - \frac{\partial\phi_i}{\partial t \partial x^j}(0, p) + \sum_k \frac{\partial \phi^k}{\partial t}(0, p)\frac{\partial\phi_i}{\partial x^k \partial x^j}(0, p).
\end{align*}
However, $\frac{\partial\phi_i}{\partial x^k \partial x^j}(0, p) = 0$ for all $k$, since $\phi_i(0, p) = p$. So in the end, we have
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|_{t=0} \left[ \frac{\partial{\phi_i}}{\partial x^j}(-t, \phi_t(p))\right] = - \frac{\partial\phi_i}{\partial t \partial x^j}(0, p),
$$
which is what we wanted.